# Multiple activity result won't add data

Tags: java, android, database, android-intent

In my activity i have one TextView and two buttons calibrate and wifi. Both button will go to scan activity to get some result. the differences is that calibrate button will save the result to reading table and wifi button will save the result to wifi table. But both button only insert it to reading table.

Here's the activity class

```
          calibrate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(db.getFriendlyWifis(building).isEmpty()) {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Select one or more Friendly WiFi";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scan.class);
                    intent.putExtra("POSITION_NAME", positionName.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("isLearning", isLearning);
                    intent.putExtra("NUMBER_OF_SECONDS", readingCount);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        });

        wifi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(db.getFriendlyWifis(building).isEmpty()) {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Select one or more Friendly WiFi";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scan.class);
                    intent.putExtra("POSITION_NAME", positionName.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("isLearning", isLearning);
                    intent.putExtra("NUMBER_OF_SECONDS", readingCount);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        });


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int result, Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode == 0){

            if(result == RESULT_OK){
                positionData = (PositionData) intent
                        .getSerializableExtra("PositionData");
                Log.v("Before db : ", positionData.toString());
                db.addReadings(building, positionData);
                positions = db.getPositions(building);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, positions);
                positionsList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, result, intent);
            }

        }

        if(requestCode == 1){

            if(result == RESULT_OK){
                positionData = (PositionData) intent
                        .getSerializableExtra("PositionData");
                Log.v("Before db : ", positionData.toString());
                db.addWifi(building, positionData);
                positiond = db.getWifi(building);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, positiond);
                positionsList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, result, intent);
            }

        }
        }
```

Comment: You're using the same request code – `SCAN_REQUEST` – in both `startActivityForResult()` calls. You apparently meant to use `0` for `calibrate`, and `1` for `wifi`, whatever the corresponding names for those would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the same request code `SCAN_REQUEST` on both the `startActivityForResult()`.

In `calibrate.setOnClickListener()`,  call `startActivityForResult` like this: `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`.

In `wifi.setOnClickListener`, call `startActivityForResult` like this: `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`

Or, instead of 0 and 1, use the corresponding variables to which 0 and 1 are assigned to.

Comment: ohh,  i see. Thank's.